# Decode IR (RC5) steps

Tags: decode, infrared

I have captured the IR signal ( I believe RC5) of a HVAC remote control, like this one....
(using [Saleae](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.saleae.com%2F&ei=SHVLVMWpNdGw7AauwIHAAg&usg=AFQjCNFbmfbNtL86MOmWFjjp2ZBlXppSIg&sig2=lA53cVucOmNAbaw3otgNwg))

[image]

This gave me a sequence of pulses of different width that I can make the Arduino reproduce and the HVAC recognize the request. An example is:

```
unsigned int power_ON[180] = {2888,3918,1911,1049,907,1992,903,989,1936,1023,907,1049,903,989,903,1049,903,1049,907,1992,1851,1992,1915,1049,928,963,928,1023,903,1049,907,1049,928,963,928,1023,903,1053,928,1023,928,963,928,1023,928,1027,928,1023,928,963,928,1023,907,1049,928,1023,928,1906,1941,959,2940,3866,1962,997,932,1967,929,963,1962,997,933,1019,959,933,933,1023,954,997,928,1971,1902,1941,1941,1019,958,933,958,997,954,997,933,1019,959,933,959,997,954,997,928,1023,958,933,958,997,954,997,933,1019,958,933,958,997,954,997,933,1019,958,1881,1962,937,2940,3862,1966,993,958,1941,933,959,1966,993,958,997,954,937,954,997,933,1023,954,1941,1880,1966,1962,997,954,937,928,1023,933,1023,954,997,928,963,928,1023,933,1023,929,1023,928,963,929,1023,928,1027,928,1023,928,963,928,1023,928,1027,928,1023,928,1910,1911,989,3832};
```

Could anyone guide me on the steps to decode the message? or understand the different pulse width?

I guess there must be certain defined pulse widths? Each meaning something different?

**My initial though is that I need to:**

1) Decode raw data by converting pulses to digital 1,0

2) Identify from digital data each section of the code, I think all the configuration is send on every key press, so identify the section of the code where it states the temperature, fan speed, hvac mode, clock, etc

3) Be able to put together a full IR code based on wanted setup, instead of just saving the whole code and reproducing it.

Any hint or guideline on how to do this?

Am I on the right track?

edit:
I have tried analysing one same mode and try to figure out which pulses change, but I cant figure it out as the number of pulses varies. Here you can see Cooling mode and maximum fan speed with changing temperature setting.

here is the excel file for anyone really into helping:
http://www.filedropper.com/analysiscoolingmodefanspeedmaximum

[image]
and the end of the message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I put your pulse widths (?) into a diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FP62.jpg
Without knowing more about what this actually represents, this does not really help i guess.. 
What buttons did you press while recording this? How did you record this? 
I would try to visualize all the data you can get. Record all buttons and put what you get in diagrams. Then stare at them and maybe you will find some logic hidden in there.

Also, open the remote, look what IC's are inside and look up their datasheets. Maybe there you will find the protocol and you won't have to do any reverse engineering at all.

Keep us updated!

Comment: I have opened the remote but the IC is a custom IC as its under black blob. No luck on that either. When testing above, I press the orange button with starts/stops at the selected settings on the screen. So to only have one parameter I keep fan speed at maximum and cooling mode selected. I only vary the temperature and maybe the clock time is also being send, I dont know.